# how to use foursquare nearbylocation,twitter tweet post,post on fb?

Tags: android, facebook, twitter

foursquare , twitter , Facebook

=============================

hie everyone i'm making a project which will use nearby location for hotels n all for check in like foursquare.. 
and share these check ins on Facebook and twitter..

i have searched a lot on Google.. but not find any exact solution.

like post will be just with Log in and on sign in the post will be shared without any further interaction of user..

please tell the exact solution because i am a newbie.. and have just done initialization process like making application on Foursquare ,  twitter ,Facebook .. i m using Facebook Sdk .. and 4 jar files for twitter and for foursquare .. not get API yet. i just need nearby location feature..

thank you.

Comment: check [this](https://github.com/kataklisma/android-google-places) for how to get nearby place useing googl API

Comment: no brother i am making a application similar to foursquare for checkin purpose .. so i don't need just locations which is provided by google place API.. i want the hotels places n all which is stored in foursquare API so i'm asking about foursquare api..

Comment: have you see [this](https://live.temboo.com/library/Library/Foursquare/Checkins/)